# Issue is with chromadb library

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, chromadb

Is there any solution to install chromadb library with python 3.12

I saw somewhere in google that chromadb library is not suits for python 3.12. but still I want to know is there any option to install that library with python 3.12.

Comment: It seems that you have to roll down to 3.11 if you need it : https://github.com/chroma-core/chroma/issues/1410

Comment: You need to update chromadb was Released: Jan 3, 2024. It will work Python 3.12.2

Answer (score 0):

According to [this plan in github](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/17842#issuecomment-1936484800), chromadb do not yet support Python 3.12.

Please roll down to python3.11.

ONNX supports python 3.12: microsoft/onnxruntime#17842 (comment). Chroma is planning support for Python 3.12.